# How do I find out what physical drive a file is on?

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to find out what physical media a file is on (either by filename or by handle).

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207641/determine-what-physical-hard-drive-a-file-is-on) that I can determine the physical drive of a given partition handle with a `DeviceIoControl` call.

But how do I get a partition handle from a filename? (Because NTFS allows to mount partitions in folders, I can't simply go by drive letter.)

The reason I'm asking is that copying a file to another physical drive is fastest when using asynchronous methods, but on the same drive it is fastest when done synchronously with a larger buffer. I want to write a function to determine the optimum copying algorithm for a given file and destination.

Comment: I would expect that you would have to search all connected media for the file, as Windows does not keep a table that maps filenames to volume letters.

Comment: I hope you mean *logical* drive. My SQL server, for example, has its primary data store on three SAS 15K drives running in RAID5. The files stored on the RAID are on *all* of the drives (spread acrosss them) simultaneously.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, but I'd still like use synchronous copying if two logical drives reside on the same physical drive (if that is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumes in Windows are generally mapped to drive letters (except on network shares).

You can create a volume file device handle on the source and destination using `CreateFile()` just passing in the drive letter path (ie: \\.\C:\).  Use the returned handle with `DeviceIoControl()`.  Compare the physical drives between the source and destination, and you should be good.

Discussion explained here: "To obtain the physical drive identifier for a volume, open ..."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Actually, volumes are mapped to drive letters, but they do not *have* to be mapped.  Unmapped volumes are still accessible through the NT namespace by using the Win32 API bypass prefix `\\.\`.  They can be created, opened, read, and written.

Comment: I can't go by drive letter because a volume might be mounted in a directory on another volume. I probably need to use `GetVolumePathName` and `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint` to sort that out, and then resolve the volume name (which is a symlink to "\Device\HarddiskVolumeX"). Then I could enumerate the "HarddiskYPartitionZ" devices and see which one points to the device  X I just resolved. Then Y is my physical drive.

Comment: Once you have the volume from `GetVolumePathName()`, you likely will still be able to use `CreateFile()` on it as I suggested.